# What are all of the possible orders of $K$? Justify your answer.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $K\le A_5$.  Assume that $K$ is cyclic.  What are all of the possible orders of $K$?  Justify your answer.

So I know that $|K|\in\{1,2,3,5\}$ but I'm not sure how to justify it.

Comment: What are the possible orders of elements of $A_5$? Or first, what are the possible orders of elements of $S_5$?

Comment: $|A_5|= \frac{S_5}{2}=\frac{5!}{2}=60$\
So the possible orders of K are $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,10,12,15,20,30,60\}$
And that's without assuming K is cyclic

Comment: What do the elements of $S_5$ look like? Can an element have order $60$, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $K\leqslant A_5$; with $K$ cyclic. Then $K$ is generated by one element, $\sigma\in A_5$, so $K=\langle \sigma\rangle$. Now, it remains to determine the order of $\sigma$. Now, what are the possible cycle types of $\sigma$? Why does this give you the answer? For example, $\sigma$ can be the identity, so $|K|=1$. It can also be a product of *disjoint* transpositions, and $|K|=2$.

**SPOILER**

> Remember that the cycle type of an element in $S_5$ can be $(1),(12),(123),(1234)(12345)$,$(123)(45),(12)(34)$ but only $(1);(123),(12345),(12)(34)$ are in $A_5$. Thus $\sigma$ has cycle type $(1),(123),(12345),(12)(34)$. These elements have order $1,3,5,2$ respectively, and those are the possible orders.